# Перевернуть в строке слова с определенной длиной, сохраняя порядок слов

Tags: python, строки, list

Как перевернуть в строке слова с определенной длиной, сохраняя порядок строки; как изменять список, не теряя порядок значений?

Нужно перевернуть слова с длиной >=5, например "Hey fellow warriors" должен возвращать "Hey wollef sroirraw"
Возможно ли сделать это с помощью for? Если создавать 2 пустых списка, то при их сложении теряется порядок слов строки. С помощью чего его можно сохранить? Мне неясно, как вообще изменять список, не теряя порядок значений.

```
#sentence = "Hey fellow warriors"
#sentence = "This is a test"

sentence = "This sentence is a sentence"



def spin_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    p = [o[::-1] for o in words if len(o)>=5]
    return(p)
    # данном случае возвращает ['ecnetnes', 'ecnetnes'], если пишем без if len(o)>=5, вернет просто перевернутую строку
      
print(spin_words(sentence))
```

Comment: Если возможно, то можно подробнее разжевать все, ведь задача с codewars, хочу все понять а решения можно и так посмотреть

Answer (score 2):

У вас уже был почти готовый код. Нужно было немного скорректировать списковое включение - `o[::-1] if len(o) >= 5 else o` вместо `if len(o)>=5`, а также добавить `join()` для склеивания слов во фразу. `o[::-1] if len(o) >= 5 else o` - это тернарный условный оператор, означающий: перевернуть слово, если длина больше или равна 5, иначе не переворачивать.

```
sentence = "This sentence is a sentence"

def spin_words(sentence):
    return ' '.join(o[::-1] if len(o) >= 5 else o for o in sentence.split())

print(spin_words(sentence))
```

```
This ecnetnes is a ecnetnes
```

Comment: Боже, я даже не думал что можно использовать 2 цикла сразу, где можно посмотреть как это работает? А спасибо большое, что все расписали

Comment: Здесь 1 явный цикл, точнее, генератор

Comment: Увидел, разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = "Hey fellow warriors"
#sentence = "This is a test"

#sentence = "This sentence is a sentence"



def spin_words(sentence):
    p=''
    for el in sentence.split():
      # if len(el)>5:
        if len(el)>=5:
            p+=el[::-1]+' '
        else:
            p+=el+' '
  # return p
    return p.strip()

def main():
    print(spin_words(sentence))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
Hey wollef sroirraw
```

Comment: SHTO? Спасибо большое. Буду упорно несколько дней выкупать ваш  код

Comment: Что-то пропустил >=5  и еще p.strip() Чтобы убрать последний пробел

Answer (score 1):

Могу написать подробное объяснение своего решения для начинающих:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if len(words[i]) >= 5:
            words[i] = words[i][::-1]
    return " ".join(words)
```

Функция разбивает строку на слова с помощью метода **split()** и сохраняет их в список **words**, затем функция перебирает в цикле все слова и проверяет длину. Если длина равна или больше 5 то она переворачивает слово используя срез **[::-1]**. Данный срез возвращает все элементы списка в обратном порядке и сохраняет обратно в список **words**. После используем **" ".join(words)** что бы объединить слова обратно в строку разделяя пробелами.

Использование:

```
print(spin_words("Hey fellow warriors"))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо